# How to determine business object state - .NET, NHibernate

Tags: .net, object, nhibernate

During developement process of my ASP.NET MVC + NHibernate application I came accross tough (for me) problem.

In my projects domain I have objects, lets call them "articles" (like on BBC website or something like this). This articles are described by few properties:

-Author
-Creation date
-IsTemp
-IsApproved

These objects can be in few states:

- Temp - IsTemp == true, everything else is not important
- Approved - IsApproved == true
- Pending - IsTemp == false && IsApproved == false && CreationDate + 10 days > DateTime.Now
- Expired - IsTemp = false && IsApproved == false && CreationDate + 10 days < DateTime.Now

(Above description is just an example- my domain is a bit more complicated but the problem is identical)

And here is the question: When should I detect articles states?
I want user to be able to list for exemple all  Approved articles etc.

- Should I use background proccess to update state of all articles every 10 minutes? It's kinda smelly for me.
- Should I use my Article class (method GetState or something?) - then I loose ability to query states by HQL and I'm forcing to get all entities from DB in order to perform paging and discovering state
- Should I prepare state-specific queries? (Repository.GetAll(State.Temp)) - this one is also smelly because I don't want to my business rules (which can change/extend) to leak into my DAL layer.
- Should I extend extend NHibernate functionality? I never did that so I don't know if this is real.

This is a big problem for me. Any ideas?

Best regards,
Karczas

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the state machine pattern [as implemented for example here](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/).

Comment: I saw similar solutions but the problem is that in one request article state is Pending and on another request (i.e. 100ms after) it could be for example Expired. Time is one of factors that changes states so persistent state are not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I would recalculate the status every time when one of the state-source-properties have changed.

So for example the `IsApproved property-setter` would call the `RecalculateStatus() method`.

'RecalculateStatus()' should only change the status if there is a change in status.
this way you can safely call 'RecalculateStatus()' any time you like

Comment: Great, but mind that time is one of the factors that can change the status. My programmer instinct (sic! ;)) want me to avoid queries like this: "from articles a where a.CreationDate.AddDays(10) > GetDate()". I consider creating some background thread to update states but problem of querying wouldn't be solved this way.